# How to report one time metric using OpenTelemetry

Tags: prometheus

I want to instrument my application to report the execution time of my parser function as a metric. The metric attributes will include an ID for each request, and I aim to create a bar graph where each bar represents the parsing time per ID.

For this purpose, I am utilizing Prometheus with Grafana and OpenTelemetry Python metrics. I have attempted to use UpAndDownCounter, Histogram, and Gauge, but I am encountering a recurring issue. After reporting the value for some parsing, it continues to report it at every interval. Consequently, instead of obtaining a single point for each metric, I end up with an infinite line of the same value.

How can I report a metric only once and ensure that I get just one point on the graph using OpenTelemetry metrics?

Comment: I would recommend to check how Prometheus handle staleness logic.